# VB dot net session value set in text box not change

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vba

In one of my vb page i am setting the value of a textbox through the value coming from session. In the same page i want to perform an edit operation of the record. On the page load i displayed the variables in textboxes and after editing values when i submit  and take the value from the textboxes, it still take the value i set through session. It do not take the value changed in the textbox rather it shows the value assigned at the time of page load. Please help.

Here is my code,

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim var As String
        var = Session("S2").ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = var
        Session.Remove("S2")
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from HouseDetails where OccupantName= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read)
            Label1.Text = dr(1)
            Label2.Text = dr(2)
            Label3.Text = dr(3)
            TextBox3.Text = dr(4)
            DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text = dr(5)
            TextBox2.Text = dr(6)
            TextBox4.Text = dr(7)
            TextBox5.Text = dr(8)
            DropDownList4.Text = dr(9)
        End While
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String = ("UPDATE HouseDetails SET OccupantName='" & TextBox1.Text & "' where HouseNum='" & Label3.Text & "'")
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add postback prevention with the line "If (Page.IsPostBack = false) Then", for not assigning the same value again to the textbox,

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If (Page.IsPostBack = false) Then
        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim var As String
        var = Session("S2").ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = var
        Session.Remove("S2")
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from HouseDetails where OccupantName= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read)
            Label1.Text = dr(1)
            Label2.Text = dr(2)
            Label3.Text = dr(3)
            TextBox3.Text = dr(4)
            DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text = dr(5)
            TextBox2.Text = dr(6)
            TextBox4.Text = dr(7)
            TextBox5.Text = dr(8)
            DropDownList4.Text = dr(9)
        End While
        cn.Close()
  End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String = ("UPDATE HouseDetails SET OccupantName='" & TextBox1.Text & "' where HouseNum='" & Label3.Text & "'")
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I fancy you're missing a check for `IsPostBack` to see whether or not this is a new request or a submission.

```
If (Not IsPostBack) Then
  ' populate for first load
End If
```

Comment: i am new to dot net. Please tell me where to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code in IsPostback property.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If (!IsPostBack) Then
        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim var As String
        var = Session("S2").ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = var
        Session.Remove("S2")
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from HouseDetails where OccupantName= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read)
            Label1.Text = dr(1)
            Label2.Text = dr(2)
            Label3.Text = dr(3)
            TextBox3.Text = dr(4)
            DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text = dr(5)
            TextBox2.Text = dr(6)
            TextBox4.Text = dr(7)
            TextBox5.Text = dr(8)
            DropDownList4.Text = dr(9)
        End While
        cn.Close()
  End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        cn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=nnn-PC;Initial Catalog=Faculty Housing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=nnn;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String = ("UPDATE HouseDetails SET OccupantName='" & TextBox1.Text & "' where HouseNum='" & Label3.Text & "'")
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```